# Trouble understanding $G$-module.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, modules, representation-theory

In the book *The Symmetric Group* by Sagan the author defines a $G$-module to be a vector space $V$ that has a multiplication $g\mathbf{v}$ of elements of $g\in G$ with elements of $\mathbf{v}\in V$ such that

1. $g\mathbf{v}\in V$
2. $g(c\mathbf{v}+d\mathbf{w})=c(g\mathbf{v})+d(g\mathbf{w})$,
3. $(gh)\mathbf{v}=g(h\mathbf{v})$
4. $\epsilon\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}$
   for all $g,h\in G; \mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\in V$; and $c,d$ in the field.

He later writes that if we have a matrix representation $X$ of degree $d$ and let $V$ be a vector space of column vectors of length $d$, then we can define a $G$-module by
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
g\mathbf{v}:=X(g)\mathbf{v},\qquad g\in G,\mathbf{v}\in V.
\end{equation}
However, I try to see how this can fulfill condition 3 above (associativity), but it does not seem to add up. Because eq. $(1)$ is the same as saying that for each $v_i$ in the basis, we have
$$\tag{2}
gv_i=\sum_j X_{ij}(g)v_j
$$
But since X is a representation we have $X(gh)=X(g)X(h)$ and thus:
$$\tag{4}
(g h) v_i=\sum_j X_{i j}(g h) v_j=\sum_{j, k} X_{i k}(g) X_{k j}(h) v_j 
$$
$$\tag{5}
g\left(h v_i\right)=g \sum_k X_{i k}(h) v_k=\sum_k X_{i k}(h) g v_k=\sum_{j, k} X_{i k}(h) X_{k j}(g)v_j
$$
So associativity does not hold. To me it seems like eq. $(1)$ should really be defined
$$
g\mathbf{v}:=\mathbf{v}^TX(g)
$$
but I could be wrong.

Comment: Hey, remember that a representation is a homomorphism. This means $X(gh)v=X(g)(X(h)v)=(X(g)X(h))v$ by assositivitu of matrix multiplication.

Comment: @RougeSegwayUser, yes, that is how I get eq. $(4)$, but why is that not equal to eq. $(5)$?

Comment: the indices in (2) are the wrong way round. The $i$th **column** of $X(g)$ should tell you what it does to $v_i$.

Comment: @MatthewTowers, yes but then we exactly get $g\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v} X(g)$ as I wrote in eq. $(6)$. But that is not how it is written in the book, which is exactly what is confusing me.

Comment: no - you've just got the indices wrong. Try it again more carefully, Sagan is correct. $\mathbf{v}X(g)$ is not a good suggestion: you are trying to multiply a $d\times 1$ column vector into a $d\times d$ matrix.

Comment: @MatthewTowers, sorry, what I meant was $g\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v} X(g)$ if we consider $\mathbf{v}$ as a row vector. If I define $g v_j=\sum_i X_{ij}(g) v_i$ then associativity holds.

Comment: @MatthewTowers, can you please help me understand what you mean by "the ith column of $X(g)$ should tell you what it does to $v_i$". From what I understand, you are saying that $v_j=\sum_i X_{ij}(g)v_i$, but this means that $g\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}^TX(g)$, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the book, we have that $V = \mathbb{C}^d$ is the space of all column vectors with entries in $\mathbb{C}$.
$X : G \rightarrow Gl_d(\mathbb{C})$ is a homomorphism (viewing the one on the right as a group under composition). In particular, this means that $X(gh) = X(g) X(h)$, by definition of a homomorphism. Notice that this induces a map $X_{ij} : G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ which is the $ij$ component of the matrix $X(g)$. The homomorphism property tells us
$$X_{ij} (gh) = \sum_{k=1}^d X_{ik}(g) X_{kj}(h).$$
Notice also we can write the group action as
$$(X(g)v)_i = \sum_{j=1}^d X_{ij}(g) v_j.$$
I think here lies the issues with your calculations - you treat $v_j \in V$ instead of a complex number. Here we're thinking of it as a number.

Putting this together,
$$(X(gh)v)_i = \sum_{j=1}^d X_{ij}(gh) v_j =  \sum_{j,k=1}^d X_{ik}(g) X_{kj}(h) v_j = \sum_{k=1}^d X_{ik}(g) (X(h)v)_k = (X(g) (X(h)v))_i. $$
We get the same vector on both ends.

If V is a general $\mathbb{C}$ vector space of dimension $d$, then we have an isomorphism between $V$ and $\mathbb{C}^d$ (what might that be?) and we're using this identification when talking about things via matrices (most likely one doesn't have to use this identification but for the sake of clarity we might as well).

**Edit:** To emphasize my point, write out your vector $v = \sum_{i=1}^d v_i e_i$, where $e_i$ is a basis. Now

$$X(g)v = X(g)\left( \sum_{j=1}^d v_i e_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^d v_i X(g)(e_i).$$

Recall that the matrix $X(g)$ acts on the vector $e_i$ by $X(g)(e_j) = \sum_{i=1}^d X_{ji}(g)e_i.$ So we get

$$X(g)v = X(g)\left( \sum_{i=1}^d v_i e_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^d v_i \sum_{k=1}^d X_{ki}(g) e_k = \sum_{k=1}^d \left(\sum_{i=1}^d X_{ki}(g) v_i \right) e_k.$$

If we project onto the subspace spanned by $e_k$, we get

$$ (X(g)v)_k = \sum_{i=1}^d X_{ki}(g) v_i,$$

which matches my formula from earlier. Now try the same calculations with this.

Comment: But $v_j$ _is_ a vector - it is one of the basis vectors (maybe I should have written them in bold-face to avoid confusion). So I am writing $\mathbf{v}$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors (see it as the simplest possible case where all coefficients $\alpha_i$ are one in the equation $\mathbf{v}=\sum_i \alpha_i v_i$).

Comment: Three questions:
1) What is the vector space of column vectors of length $d$?
2) What is the basis of this vector space?
3) What does a matrix acting on this vector space look like? More precisely, given $A$ a $d \times d$ matrix, what does $A$ look like, and what does $Av$ look like?

Comment: I appreciate your effort. But note we are using different notations. What you call $e_i$ is what I called $v_i$. And if you in the second-last equation consider $v=e_i$, then that equation turns into $X(g) e_i=\sum_k X_{k i}(g) e_k=\boldsymbol{e}^T X(g)$, which is what I wrote in my last equation of the post.

Comment: What is $\mathbf{e}$ in this context? 

Maybe this will make it clearer -- just work in $\mathbb{R}^2$. We have $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \cdot e_1 = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} = a e_1 + b e_2$. This checks out with what you wrote and with what I wrote. If $\mathbf{e} = (e_1, e_2)^T$, then we can expand it as $\mathbf{e} = ((1,0)^T,(0,1)^T)^T$. Notice that it doesn't make sense to evaluate $\mathbf{e}^T \cdot \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ without further clarification of what the action is (it's not just the usual one).

Comment: Maybe to clarify it more, Sagan is thinking about a vector space of dimension $d$, which you can identify with column vectors in $\mathbb{C}^d$. I think you're talking about the vector space of column vectors with entries in a vector space of dimension $d$; this has dimension $d^2$, so you can see right away something is wrong. If you define the action and spaces appropriately, you can probably make it make sense and maybe that aligns with what you're claiming, but its something else entirely.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.